# Get values from JSON and send them by html email

Tags: python-3.x

I`m building a little script that will send my weather info every morning. I figured out how to send email, and I know how to call an api using requests. The only thing that i do not know is how to pass the values that im interested to the html body of email. Here is the code : https://gist.github.com/Cosaquee/9bda190097a3eef23073.

Can someone tell me how to do it ? Should I use .format ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code you'll want to use json.loads to decode the returned json. For example, my_decodejson = json.loads(r).  See https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html.  Then you should be able to process the my_decodejson like a dictionary.  The html string will look something like

```
`
HTML = """\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>Hi!<br>
    Your weather is"""" + weather + """</br>
    Have a nice day...."""
`
```

HTH.